# Are $f$ and $g\cdot f$ associates?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-groups

Assume $\mathbb{K}$ is algebraically closed field. Let $V\subset\mathbb{A}^n$ be an irreducible affine variety. Assume $\mathbb{K}[V]$ is NOT an U.F.D. Suppose we have a regular action of a connected linear algebraic group $G$ on $V$ (hence, it induces an action on $\mathbb{K}[V]$, namely, $g\cdot f(x)=f(g^{-1}x)$, $f\in\mathbb{K}[V],x\in V$ and $g\in G$). Let $f\in\mathbb{K}[V]$ be an irreducible element such that vanishing set $\mathcal{V}(f)$ is irreducible and $G$-stable (so, $\mathcal{V}(f)=\mathcal{V}(g\cdot f)$). Is it true that $f$ and $g\cdot f$ have to be associates?

Or, can we add some condition on $f$ or $(f)$ such that $f$ and $g\cdot f$ will be associates?